# How can I put back the root default environment in Python?

Tags: python, command-line, conda

Long time ago when I didn't know what I was doing and I changed the root environment directory of python (I don't remember how I did it).
Everytime I open my terminal and type `which python` I get
**/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/bin/python**
and I want to run the global python, so every time I have to type `conda deactivate` in terminal in order to get 
**/usr/bin/python**
So basically what I want is that when I type `which python` for the first time I get 
**/usr/bin/python**
instead of the conda package.
Is there also a command like `conda info --envs` to get all the environments that you have outside the conda package? Such as list like: 
base      *  /usr/bin/python           Where the * would mean the root of python *(Python 2.7.16)*  
 
            /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3 *(Python 3.8.0)*
            /Users/user/opt/anaconda3/condabin/conda

Comment: Are you using the correct terminal. The anaconda terminal runs the anaconda environments while the other local python can be run on cmd terminal.

Comment: Seems like you have conda but don't want to have it. Try removing it, or maybe you have auto activation of your conda-enviroment in your `bash.sh`. If nothing work, have you tried installing your OS again? Based on the information you provide this is my best suggestion.

Comment: I checked and what happens is that everytime I open my terminal, it opens automatically conda.  I get  (base) Users-MacBook-Air:~ Uriel$ . And I should only get Users-MacBook-Air:~ Uriel$ when I open it